# PHP not able to add object to JSON

Tags: php, json

The below code converts the rss feed xml data to json and returns as JSON API.
I need to send the headers of the rss feed too along with result.
So I am trying to add a key called 'headers'

PHPSCRIPT.php?feedURL=http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss

But I get an error **Warning: It is not yet possible to assign complex types to attributes in /storage/ssd1/800/19251800/public_html/feed_test.php on line 8**

```
<?php
function Parse($url) {
     $fileContents= file_get_contents($url);
     ;     
     $fileContents = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t", "&amp;","&nbsp;"), '', $fileContents);
     $fileContents = trim(str_replace('"', "'", $fileContents));
     $simpleXml = simplexml_load_file($url, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
     $simpleXml['headers'] = parseHeaders($http_response_header);
     return json_encode($simpleXml);
}

function parseHeaders( $headers )
{
    $head = array();
    foreach( $headers as $k=>$v )
    {
        $t = explode( ':', $v, 2 );
        if( isset( $t[1] ) )
            $head[ trim($t[0]) ] = trim( $t[1] );
        else
        {
            $head[] = $v;
            if( preg_match( "#HTTP/[0-9\.]+\s+([0-9]+)#",$v, $out ) )
                $head['reponse_code'] = intval($out[1]);
        }
    }
    return $head;
}

$data = Parse($_GET['feedURL']);
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo $data
?>
```

Comment: The error says it all; you're trying to assign an array to an attribute (`headers`), which is not presently supported. You'll need to convert your `headers` array into an xml structure instead and add that to the object

Comment: The parseHeaders() function does give the object as JSON.

Comment: Your `parseHeaders` function returns an array, not JSON...

Comment: I need header json that was obtained from parseHeaders() to be joined to data json. Does that make sense?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: You could `return json_encode($head)` from `parseHeaders`, but you would need to remember when decoding that you need to `json_decode` the headers after you decode the object as a whole

Comment: Sorry I am a dumb https://pastebin.com/raw/ZrvkHxdv I did this but output doesnt return headers key pair

Comment: You need to update your question with: 1. what is in `$http_response_header`, 2. what is the result you are getting and 3. what is the result you expect

Comment: This might be helpful: https://3v4l.org/frlfQ#v8.1.10